# error in your SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`cid` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`ckey` TINYTEXT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`cdate` TINYTEXT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`ctime` TINYTEXT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`cuser` TINYTEXT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`ctext` LONGTEXT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`cstatus` TINYTEXT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

MySQL said:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `cdate` TINYTEXT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `ctime` TINYTEXT UNSIGNED' at line 1

#### Updated full code:

```
$query = "
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  cid INT(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  ckey TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
  cdate TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
  ctime TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
  cuser TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
  ctext LONGTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
  cstatus TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;";
```

Comment: `TINYTEXT` is not an integer type, so `UNSIGNED` does not make sense.  It only makes sense for the integer type column.

Comment: I'll warn you against using `TINYINT` as your auto incrementing primary key unless it really suits your business need. That affords you only 255 possible values.

Comment: UNSIGNED removed still getting error
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'mytable' (
 'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 'ckey' TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
 'cdate' TINYINT NOT NULL ,
 'ctime' TINYINT NOT NULL ,
 'cuser' TINYINT NOT NULL ,
 'ctext' LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
 'cstatus' TINYINT NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;";
Query failed:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mytable'('id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 'ckey' TINYTEXT N' at line 1

Comment: That error looks like you have single quotes around mytable. It needs no quotes but may be quoted with backticks.

Comment: The above error shows first column as `id` (not `cid` as in the posted sample). Can you  post your **real** query into your original question?  Also have you tried to run this script directly not through (apparently) PHP code?

Comment: $query = "CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`cid` INT(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`ckey` TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
`cdate` TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
`ctime` TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
`cuser` TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
`ctext` LONGTEXT(10) NOT NULL ,
`cstatus` TINYTEXT(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;";

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify string max length, like:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`cid` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`ckey` TINYTEXT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`cdate` TINYTEXT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`ctime` TINYTEXT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`cuser` TINYTEXT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`ctext` LONGTEXT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`cstatus` TINYTEXT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

where 10 is your value. Hope to be useful

Comment: Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , `cdate` TINYTEXT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , `ctime` TINY' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's answering the question since I tried via php and it was not working so I did it directly

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`cid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`ckey` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`cdate` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`ctime` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`cuser` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
`ctext` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`cstatus` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```